# XML and INI Files could not be opened directly anymore on Mac

Tags: macos, warnings

I've re-Installed my MacOS (High Sierra) a couple of days ago. Today I am facing a strange (new?) Security Limitation. Whenever I try to open an INI or an XML File macOS tells me that this file is not from a verified developer ‒ the good old message you see when you download an App from the Web. But now I get it also when I try to open such files?

When I open System Preferences and Security I am able to "allow this App" aka the file ‒ when I then retry to open the File it works. But when I create a new INI or XML File I've got the same warning. I'm using Sublime Editor and have the newest version in use.

The whole system and apps are up2date.
Anyone else got this problem?

Comment: Does "Open" from the context menu (right-click) still work? If not, just open your text editor first and then open the file from its File>Open menu.

Comment: Hi Thilo: Its the same behaviour when i right click and open in Sublime. If its a new File it asks / blocks. Also when i first open the editor and drag the file into it... I am downloading actualy dreamweaver to have a look what happens there but i think it would be the same because it blocks the File itself...